# How can access XSLT child node relative to my current for-each?

Tags: xslt-2.0

using XSLT-2.0, I have something like

> ```
> <A>
>   <item1/>
>   <item2/>
>   <B>
>     <itema/>
>     <itemb/>
>   </B>
>  </A>
> ```

I know each A will contain one and only one B. I cant change the XML. How can I write XSLT to display these all *as if* there was no B-nodes, like

```
item1   item2   itemA    itemB
```

I tried what seemed sort of syntactically and logically ok, hoping it might recognize it, but apparently not supported:

> ```
> <xsl:for-each select="A">
>  <td><xsl:value-of select="item1"/></td>
>  <td><xsl:value-of select="item2"/></td>
>  <td><xsl:value-of select="B/itema"/></td>
>  <td><xsl:value-of select="B/itemb"/></td>
> </xsl:for-each>
> ```

I can understand why this would be problematic since the parser would wonder, for the general case, "which B does he want??"..

Comment: your code seems okay but I suspect a default namespace in your input xml (e.g., `xmlns="www.namespace.com"`)

Comment: Please show an _accurate_ sample of your actual input XML document, and a complete, but still minimal,  XSLT stylesheet. Thanks. Help: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  mlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" >

Comment: Mathias I'll have to work on a more detailed example- the docs I have are all proprietary

Comment: If your code isn't working then it's because of something that you haven't shown us.

Comment: The inputs that my *approach* was ok were enough to get it working. I reworked the code and it's all 100% now. I dunno if I had a non-printing char or what, but I deleted and re-entered the value-of sections and we're good to go. Thanks to all who replied- there seems to be very little documenation on *relative value-of* entries and few exmples of same...